# is there anyway to make system.io.path work with /

Tags: c#

I need to manipulate paths that are/a/b/c/xxx etc. But Path class is determined that separators must be `\`. So if I do

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName("/a/b/c/xxx");
```

I get "\a\b\c"

I know I can write code to do it myself but I wonder if there is a knob for Path that I haven't found yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path functions will only work with paths that are appropriate with your operating system. I suggest you just use a string.Replace.

```
string.Replace("/", @"\")
```